# Unable to install EE - config.php and database.php not being written

Tags: php-errors, database-error

When installing EE - I get the dreaded database connection error. I've verified the DB works with the credentials by connecting locally in mysql with the same info. I've also utilized your dbtest.php and verified it works.

The problem appears to be EE isn't writing config.php and database.php. The files are zero byte after I hit install.

I've verified permissions and ownership on both files, as well as the other files as required by the installation script.

Is there potentially some php or apache config that is required to allow these files to be written? Please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Jimmy - I'd strongly suggest you report this as a bug via [EllisLab's Bug Tracker](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs) if you believe it to be a general bug (though I feel positive I've used passwords with `%` in my DB credentials in the past).

Comment: Jimmy - This site is not run by EE, just us groupies.

Comment: I just verified that you can in fact use a `%` sign in your DB credentials during an install, at least with 2.7.2. No database errors encountered, install completed normally.

Comment: Jimmy - if you have found a solution you can post this in the "answer" box below (I've just done this for you). Think of this site as a Q&A wiki. Also, as others mentioned, this is a community-run site, not managed by Ellislab, so if you want their attention you will need to report a bug through their official channels or email them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution posted in question:

Apparently there is an undocumented bug in EE -

if your database password contains a percent symbol EE will fail to finish installation and configuration, thereby leaving you with a 'unable to connect to database' error on the second screen of install.